# Enumerable.Max() if two max values

Tags: c#, enumerable

I'm trying to get the maximum value from an array of integers but if there are two values which are considered maximum, I need to find their index in the array.

I.e. If I have the array:
{10, 13, 13, 9, 8}
I need to find the index of both the 13 values

If I have the array:
{10, 13, 12, 9, 8}
I need to just return the index of the 13

I have done the second part of this by using
    `myArray.ToList().IndexOf(myArray.Max());`

But can't figure out the first example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
var array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 8, 2, 3, 6, 8, 8, 4, 3, 2, 8, 1, 8 };

var maxNumber = array.Max();

var indices =
    array.Select((number, index) => number == maxNumber ? index : -1)
         .Where(index => index != -1);
```

It gives back the array of all max number indices. We're selecting index value for number that equals array max number and -1 for every other value. Since array index starts at zero, we will never get -1 as index of array max number. That means, after we filter our selection with condition `index != -1` we'll get only indices of max numbers we selected before.

Fiddle example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/drRiVb

Comment: I do like your solution, but as it stands it has `O(n^2)` performance. Fine for small lists, but would slow down quickly for large lists. It could easily be modified to have `O(2n)` perf.

Comment: @Enigmativity Changed it.

Comment: This seems to do everything I want it to do and a nice simple solution. Also really appreciate the Fiddle Example. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of LINQ works:

```
var numbers = new [] { 10, 13, 13, 9, 8 };

var maxIndices =
    numbers
        .Select((n, i) => new { n, i })
        .GroupBy(x => x.n, x => x.i)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key)
        .Take(1)
        .SelectMany(x => x)
        .ToArray();
```

This gives the result:

[image: result]

Remembering that arrays are zero-based the above two values are the indices for the `13`'s in the array.

Comment: Will this also work if the array only has one maximum number? I should probably add that I'm not sure of the condition that the array is in so I can't be sure how many maximums there will be.

Comment: @thebluelad - Yes, it will work with a single maximum. It will return an array with only one element in that case.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the `ToArray()` unless definitely needed, if the next bit of code is going to only go through the values once, then that's a waste.

Comment: For that matter, `Take(1).SelectMany(x => x)` can just be `First()`.

Comment: @JonHanna - It's there to force the execution of the LINQ to ensure it happens only once. Useless if you know you're only iterating once, but useful as a good habit when you don't.

Comment: @JonHanna - I explicitly didn't use `.First()` as it will fail when the list is empty. `.Take(1).SelectMany(x => x)` always works.

Comment: Yes, `.FirstOrDefault() ?? Enumerable.Empty<int>()` would be better than `First()`. `ToArray()` though is still encouraging bad habits, and calling it "a good habit" more so. You either know how often you are going to iterate it, in which case you can use `ToArray()` or not accordingly, or you don't, in which case you can let the code further up that does know call `ToArray()`, or perhaps `ToList()` as might be more appropriate to that code, which only that code can know about. Otherwise you're wasting time and memory and forcing the execution of the Linq when it might be aborted.

Comment: @JonHanna - I think we might need to agree to disagree on what constitutes a good habit with calling `.ToArray()`. You're clearly a smart guy - I've looked at your other answers and you have more rep points than I do - so you clearly know what you're talking about. But I think it boils down to a judgement call based on information we don't actually have from the OP. It could go either way.

Comment: I didn't test your method for correctness, just for performance. It is very slow.

Comment: @Lorek - Can you elaborate on what timings you did, with what source, and what you compared it to?

Comment: @Lorek - Yes, you're right. I did some timings myself. msmolcic's answer is the best - nice and fast, while still simple to understand.

Comment: My testing has Jon Hanna's first solution as the fastest, mine second, then msmolcic. I used the original poster's data over a million iterations.

Comment: @Enigmativity you can't make the judgement call to call or not call `ToArray()` if what you called into made the decision to call `ToArray()` for you, but you can always decide to add `ToArray()` after a call to something that didn't, hence the habit to develop being to not call it until you actively decide to do so. Imagine if all the methods of `Enumerable` internally called it!

Comment: (Though that said, I think whoever down-voted went too far. Indeed, I upvoted).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    private static IEnumerable<int> FindIndexesOfMax(int[] input)
    {
        int max = input.Max();
        for (int i=0; i<input.Length; i++)
        {
            if (input[i] == max)
                yield return i;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is recommended to explain your code, so that he (and future viewers) can learn the *concept*, not simply copy and paste.

Comment: Also, why bother going through the list twice?

Comment: @JonHanna, brevity and simplicity. It's of course better to only iterate over the items once. But this code is still pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with all linq providers (your mentioning `Enumerable.Max()` rather than "Linq's `Max()` in the title suggests you don't, but maybe you do), then I'd suggest Enigmativity's answer, but without the `ToArray()` unless definitely needed.

If you only care about enumerables, I'd suggest:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> MaxIndices(this IEnumerable<int> source)
{
  using(var en =  source.GetEnumerator())
  {
    if (!en.MoveNext())
      return Enumerable.Empty<int>();
    int curMax = en.Current;
    List<int> indices = new List<int>{ 0 };
    for (int index = 1; en.MoveNext(); ++index)
    {
      int current = en.Current;
      if (current == curMax)
        indices.Add(index);
      else if (current > curMax)
      {
        indices.Clear();
        indices.Add(index);
        curMax = current;
      }
    }
    return indices;
  }
}
```

This starts either by returning an empty enumerable (if there are no values in the source, there are hence no maximum values) or else starting with a list containing `0` as the starting point is always that the first element is the maximum found so far. From that starting point it continues through the list. If a given element matches the maximum found so far then its index is added to the list of indices. If a given element is greater than the maxmimum found so far, then it becomes the new maximum, and the list is cleared before its index is added. Otherwise the value is ignored.

You can combine both approaches with appropriate overloads. As well as the above have:

```
  public static IQueryable<int> MaxIndices(this IQueryable<int> source)
  {
    if (source is EnumerableQuery<int>)
      return MaxIndices((IEnumerable<int>)source).AsQueryable(); // most efficient approach with enumerables.
    return source.Select((n, i) => new { n, i })
      .GroupBy(x => x.n, x => x.i)
      .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key)
      .FirstOrDefault() ?? Enumerable.Empty<int>().AsQueryable();
  }
```

Then it takes the most efficient approach for either case, including treating queryables that are actually enumerables as enumerables. All other sources are treated much as in Enigmativity's answer.